# In terraform, how do you sort a list of objects and grab the last value?

Tags: terraform

Given the following list of objects where order is not guaranteed.  How do I use terraform to sort a list and grab the latest value?

```
locals {
  list_of_objects = [
    {
      name                    = "0.25388.50855"
      sort_versions_by_semver = false
      tags = {
        "baseosimg" = "windows2022datacenter"
      }
    },
    {
      name                    = "0.25424.21095"
      sort_versions_by_semver = false
      tags = {
        "baseosimg" = "windows2022datacenter"
      }
    },
    {
      name                    = "0.25399.6325"
      sort_versions_by_semver = false
      tags = {
        "baseosimg" = "windows2022datacenter"
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terraform if you convert the list of objects to a map, it will automatically sort it.  From there you can grab the last value (or first).

```
locals {
  map_of_sorted_objects = { for a in local.list_of_objects : a.name => a }
}

output "test" {
  value = lookup(
    local.map_of_sorted_objects,
    element(
      sort(keys(local.map_of_sorted_objects)),
      length(local.map_of_sorted_objects) - 1
    )
  )
}
```

Output

```
test = {
  "name" = "0.25424.21095"
  "sort_versions_by_semver" = false
  "tags" = {
    "baseosimg" = "windows2022datacenter"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a documentation link that shows converting a list to a map automatically sorts it? Your solution seems like a lot of extra steps, versus just using the `sort()` function: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/sort

Comment: Sort only operates on a list of strings, how do you propose to sort a list of objects?  I could be explicit with keys = sort(keys()).

Comment: Yeah I think your edit is more foolproof, unless you can find something in the docs saying a map is always sorted in Terraform. Otherwise that might just be a side-effect of the specific version of Terraform you are running.

Comment: FWIW, I read about it in the developers forums. One of the developers mentioned it, I couldn't find documentation to support it.

Comment: Maps/objects are automatically sorted lexicographically (word?) by key not according to the documentation, but according to multiple accounts from the development team. I believe this is derived from the identical Golang type.